# Send a button value with jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a litle problem with the following code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#click").click(function() {
        var jegy = $(this).attr('value');
        var dataString = $("#jegyform").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "jegybeiras.php",
            data: dataString + '&jegy=' + jegy,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#jegyek").html(html);
            }
        });

    });
}); 
</script>
```

And a form where is the following buttons (and other inputs)

```
<button id="click" name="jegy" type="submit" value="p5">5</button>
<button id="click" name="jegy" type="submit" value="p4">4</button>
<button id="click" name="jegy" type="submit" value="p3">3</button>
<button id="click" name="jegy" type="submit" value="p2">2</button>
<button id="click" name="jegy" type="submit" value="p1">1</button>
```

My question is that, how can I post the clicked button value, it is working now but randomly for 4th-5th clicking on the actual button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `id` to `class= "click"` in each your button input and then try your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".click").click(function() {
        var jegy = $(this).attr('value');
        var dataString = $("#jegyform").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "jegybeiras.php",
            data: dataString + '&jegy=' + jegy,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#jegyek").html(html);
            }
        });

    });
 }); 
</script>
```

Note:- if you  want to add event on same type of element coming multiple time in your code. then go for class. id is used to add event on unique element.